# Text not changing color with jquery addClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/GHJX5/

I have a div with blue text and I want it to change on hover to yellow. For some reason, if I remove the CSS part that sets it blue it will change to yellow on hover, but if it's set to blue it will not.

JS

```
$('#registerbutton').hover(
    function() {
        $('#registerbutton').addClass('asd');
    }, function() {
        $('#registerbutton').removeClass('asd');
    }
);
```

HTML

```
<div id="registerbutton">click</div>
```

CSS

```
#registerbutton{
    color:blue;
}
.asd{
    color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An ID is more specific than a class, therefore the class gets overruled. Try this instead:

```
#registerbutton.asd {
    color:yellow;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GHJX5/4/)**

To learn more about CSS specificity, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: I thought that CSS that got added last time will overwrite anything from before.

Comment: Only if the calculated specificity is the same between rules will the order of the rules have an effect. In addition to the link I posted in my answer, there are sites that offer CSS specificity calculators to help you figure out the weight of a selector.

Answer (score 1):

Why you not using simple CSS property hover Like this

```
#registerbutton:hover{color:yellow;}
```

Comment: That's an option, but I wanted to understand why my example doesn't work, as well.

Comment: In css ID have more priority then Class, That may be the issue in your case.